# How can I get values from a column based on selected month and year from spinner using SQLite in Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-spinner

So, I have this code below which from my DatabaseOperations.java.
I want to sum all values from *COLUMN_JUMLAH* based on month and year selected from HitungFinalBulanActivity.java.

But before that, I want to select COLUMN_JUMLAH values from selected month and year spinner.

But I got confused on how to show the result of selected sum values into a textview. FYI, in my table, COLUMN_JUMLAH initialised as a String, and I convert the values into double type in getAllValues() method.

Anyway, I used spinner with values stored in string array.

```
private Periode cursorToPeriode(Cursor cursor){
        Periode periode = new Periode();
        Log.v("info", "The getLONG " + cursor.getLong(0));
        Log.v("info", "The setLatLng " + cursor.getString(1) + "," + cursor.getString(2) + "," + cursor.getString(3) + "," + cursor.getString(4));
        periode.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        periode.setAwalPeriode(cursor.getString(1));
        periode.setAkhirPeriode(cursor.getString(2));
        periode.setKeterangan(cursor.getString(3));
        periode.setJumlah(cursor.getString(4));
        return periode;
    }


    public ArrayList<Periode> getAllPeriode(){
        Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_PERIODE, allColumns, null,null,null,null,null);
        ArrayList<Periode> periodes = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            Periode periode = cursorToPeriode(cursor);
            periodes.add(periode);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        cursor.close();
        return periodes;
    }

    public ArrayList<Periode> getJumlahPeriode(){
        Double jumlah;
        Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_PERIODE,null, COLUMN_JUMLAH , null,null,null,null,null);
        ArrayList<Periode> periodes = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            Periode periode = cursorToPeriode(cursor);
            periodes.add(periode);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return periodes;
    }

    public int addAllValues(String bulan, String tahun){
        int total = 0;

        Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + (Double.parseDouble(COLUMN_JUMLAH)) + ") FROM " + TABLE_PERIODE + " WHERE strftime('%Y'," + tahun + ") AND strftime('%M,'"+ bulan +")", null);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            total = c.getInt(0);
        }
        return total;
    }
```

And here is my **HitungFinalBulanActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.kalkulatorakuntansi;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.kalkulatorakuntansi.Adapter.DatabaseOperations;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.time.Year;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class HitungFinalBulanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner MonthSpinner;
    Spinner YearSpinner;
    TextView result, totalJumlah;
    Integer myDb;
    private DatabaseOperations transaksiOperations;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hitung_final_bulan);

        transaksiOperations = new DatabaseOperations(this);
        transaksiOperations.Open();

        MonthSpinner = findViewById(R.id.monthSpinner);
        YearSpinner = findViewById(R.id.yearspinner);

        totalJumlah = findViewById(R.id.txtViewJumlah);
        result = findViewById(R.id.txtViewHasilBulan);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> MonthAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.months_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        MonthAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        MonthSpinner.setAdapter(MonthAdapter);

        ArrayList<String> years = new ArrayList<String>();
        int thisYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        for (int i = 2010; i <= thisYear; i++) {
            years.add(Integer.toString(i));
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> YearAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, years);
        YearSpinner.setAdapter(YearAdapter);

        myDb = transaksiOperations.addAllValues(MonthSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), YearSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

    }
}
```

I'm not sure the code will work, cause I've tried it and nothing happen. Please help me to solve this! Thank you

Here's the error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.kalkulatorakuntansi, PID: 19866
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kalkulatorakuntansi/com.example.kalkulatorakuntansi.HitungFinalBulanActivity}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "01": syntax error (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT CAST(SUM(Jumlah)as Double) FROM
>   tb_periode WHERE strftime('%Y',2010) AND strftime('%M,'01)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>        Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "01": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT CAST(SUM(Jumlah)as
>   Double) FROM tb_periode WHERE strftime('%Y',2010) AND
>   strftime('%M,'01)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1392)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1331)
>           at com.example.kalkulatorakuntansi.Adapter.DatabaseOperations.addAllValues(DatabaseOperations.java:167)
>           at com.example.kalkulatorakuntansi.HitungFinalBulanActivity.onCreate(HitungFinalBulanActivity.java:55)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Answer (score 0):

Just put your result in textview

```
myDb = transaksiOperations.addAllValues(MonthSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), YearSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

result.setText(myDb+""); // add this line to set text
```

and If you want to change textview value on spinner item selection. put above code in onItemSelected.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I got stuck here in my addAllValues() method which I want select values from COLUMN_JUMLAH by converting the COLUMN_JUMLAH from string to double then pass it to a textview in another activity?

Comment: did you get any error there? can you please share logs once?

Comment: try SUM(CAST(Jumlah AS Double))

Comment: I did that already, but I can't get the values from jumlah since it has an error while compiling where clause. My COLUMN_AWAL is in string type and I got the values from selected calender so it'll store the data with this MM/DD/YYYY format in string

Comment: As per your error logs, you are not using a valid format of Query. So it is giving you to SQLiteException. Your error at  "AND strftime('%M,'01)". So Modify your query with "AND strftime('%M',01)".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203323/discussion-between-leony-and-sushil-solanki).